# Elantech touchpad stopped working completely (Debian Jessie)

Tags: debian, touchpad

I've had this laptop for about a month and the touchpad (ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad) was working fine. Yesterday that changed. I had this weird issue with my battery where it didn't recognize that I even had a battery (acpitool said battery: "not available") and therefore it would turn off right when I unplugged the charger, as if it were a desktop computer and not a portable laptop with a rechargeable battery. Anyway, after one of these shutdowns my touchpad stopped working. Now the battery is working fine but the touchpad is not. I checked out all of the similar questions on this site but none of them worked or matched my circumstances.
Here are the details:

- No X11 cursor shows up.
- I'm running debian jessie with kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64.
- My touchpad is both recognized and enabled
- my synaptic touchpad package is fully updated
- xev shows no response from any interaction with the touchpad
- a usb mouse works, which I'm using right now
- I don't have an xorg.conf

Thanks all. I'll add anything that will help if asked. I cannot figure out what could be causing this.

```
@debian:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Mitsumi Electric Apple Optical USB Mouse  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

relevant crap in /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
[     3.878] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech 
Touchpad (/dev/input/event2)
[     3.878] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "evdev 
touchpad catchall"
[     3.878] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad 
catchall"
[     3.878] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Applying InputClass "Default 
clickpad buttons"
[     3.878] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[     3.879] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[     3.880] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     3.880]    compiled for 1.16.0.901, module version = 1.8.99
[     3.880]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[     3.880]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.0
[     3.880] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'ETPS/2 Elantech    \
Touchpad'
[     3.880] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: always reports core events
[     3.880] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[     3.913] (II) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: ignoring touch 
events for semi-multitouch device
[     3.913] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: x-axis range 0 - 
3080 (res 0)
[     3.913] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: y-axis range 0 - 
1120 (res 0)
[     3.913] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: pressure range 0 - 
255
[     3.913] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: finger width range 
0 - 15
[     3.913] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: buttons: left 
right double triple
[     3.914] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Vendor 0x2 Product 
0xe
[     3.914] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[     3.914] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: always reports core events
[     3.968] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042 
/serio1/input/input2/event2"
[     3.968] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ETPS/2 Elantech   
Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 13)
[     3.968] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) MinSpeed 
is now constant deceleration 2.5
[     3.968] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) MaxSpeed  
is now 1.75
[     3.968] (**) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) 
AccelFactor is now 0.061
[     3.968] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) keeping acceleration 
scheme 1
[     3.968] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[     3.968] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 
2.000
[     3.968] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: (accel) acceleration 
threshold: 4
[     3.968] (--) synaptics: ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: touchpad found
[     3.968] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ETPS/2 Elantech 
Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse1)
[     3.968] (**) ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad: Ignoring device from 
InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37883/discussion-on-question-by-nebulon-elantech-touchpad-stopped-working-completely).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is I am a dumbass. Sorry all. Apparently there's a keyboard shortcut that does it to the firmware. This is why I can't have nice things.